# Is there any way to validate only the enabled fields in the form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am just doing simple IP Validation on the fields inside my form. There are 12 such fields which areundergoing this validation according to my current logic. Now I want to validate only those fields which are enabled and ignore the validation for the disabled fields.
Note: I am disabling fields based on the logic and I have not set disabled attribute in html for these fields. 
Function EnableDisableDropDown is disabling the Controller B part. I dont want the validation to be performed on fields of Controller B.

JS Part

```
const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


    if (ipformat.test(mcIps[i].value)== false) {
        return dialog('Invalid MC_IP Address');
    }
    else if (ipformat.test(mcNetmasks[i].value)== false){
        return dialog('Invalid MC_Netmask Address');
    }
    else if (ipformat.test(mcGateways[i].value)== false){
        return dialog('Invalid MC_Gateway Address');
    }  
    }



function EnableDisableDropDown(abc) {
    var selectedValue = abc.options[abc.selectedIndex].value;
    var elems=document.querySelectorAll(".mc_ip,.Netmask_IP,.Gateway_IP,.RBOD_MC,.RBOD_SC,.RBOD_EC,.RBOD_FU,.ISCSI_IP,.CONTROLLER_ID");
    for(i=8; i<16; i++){
    //elems.disabled = selectedValue == '2' ? false : true;
    elems[i].disabled = selectedValue == '2' ? false : true;
} 
    for(i=24; i<32; i++){
    //elems.disabled = selectedValue == '2' ? false : true;
    elems[i].disabled = selectedValue == '2' ? false : true;
} 
}
```

HTML Part

```
<div id="extra" style="display:hidden;">

<h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
  <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
  <select class="CONTROLLER_ID" id='Controller_ID1' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='A'>A </select>
  <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input class="mc_ip" type='text' name='extra_ip1' id='mc_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP'  />
  <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text' id='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
  <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text' id='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway'  />
  <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' id='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' id='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' id='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' id='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
  <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
  <select class="CONTROLLER_ID" id='Controller_ID' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
  <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba1"  placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input class="mc_ip" type='text'  id='mcip' name='extra_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP'  />
  <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text'  id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
  <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text'  id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
  <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />

</div>
```

Comment: where is the code for validation and `if` cannot have a return statement unless it is inside a function

Comment: I am validating using the if statements itself.  I didn't use any function as was not sure how to implement a function to validate IP only for enabled fields. Using if conditions I am checking if the particular field is having the ipformat or not. Also i am using querySelectorAll to access the elements that why referencing through the index. can you please suggest how can i achieve this?